# Sticky Scrolling with div on Touch Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the the jQuery [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) plugin for adding modal windows to my site. The modal windows have scrollable content in a div. On desktop, when I open one of the modals, the scrolling is smooth. When I open a modal on a touch device, the scroll on modal is not smooth, but rather sticky and kind of stiff.

Has anyone else experienced this or know how I can add a more natural smooth scroll to my modal div?

Comment: For iOS based devices try adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!